# subset matrices: map a binary matrix onto a qualitative matrix for 1s but not 0s while keeping matrix dimension intact

Tags: r, matrix, dictionary, nested-lists

Lets say I have two list-of-lists, one being solely binary and the other one being quantitative. The order in the lists matters. I would like to map the binary matrices onto its qualitatively counterpart while creating a new list-of-lists with the same number of nested matrices with the same dimensions. These matrices will be subsets of their qualitative counterparts; where there are 1s in the binary matrices.

```
# dummy data

dat1 <- c(0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1)
mat1 <- matrix(dat1, ncol=4, nrow=4, byrow=T)

dat2 <- c(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0)
mat2 <- matrix(dat1, ncol=4, nrow=4, byrow=T)

lsMat1 <- list(mat1, mat2)

dat3 <- c(0.3,0.1,0.6,0.3,0.9,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.6,0.2,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.1,0.4,0.5)
mat3 <- matrix(dat3, ncol=4, nrow=4, byrow=T)

dat4 <- c(0.5,0.3,0.6,0.8,0.1,0.4,0.5,0.1,0.5,0.1,0.0,0.1,0.4,0.6,0.0,0.8)
mat4 <- matrix(dat4, ncol=4, nrow=4, byrow=T)

lsMat2 <- list(mat3, mat4)
```

Desired new nested list

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.0  0.1    0  0.3
[2,]  0.9  0.0    0  0.0
[3,]  0.6  0.0    0  0.0
[4,]  0.4  0.1    0  0.5

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.0  0.3    0  0.8
[2,]  0.1  0.0    0  0.0
[3,]  0.5  0.0    0  0.0
[4,]  0.4  0.6    0  0.8
```

Any pointers would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is this desired "new" list the correct value for the test data you supplied above? It doesn't appear to be correct based on your definition.

Comment: Cheers for commenting. Yeah, that was the idea, but since I did it by hand it's possible that I introduced errors. I'll check and correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume the output you supplied above is incorrect. Since you have 0's and 1's in your binary matrix and you only want to keep the 1's values, you can use simple elementwise multiplication. You can do that for each item in the list with

```
Map(`*`, lsMat1, lsMat2)
```

which returns

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.0  0.1    0  0.3
[2,]  0.9  0.0    0  0.0
[3,]  0.6  0.0    0  0.0
[4,]  0.4  0.1    0  0.5

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  0.0  0.3    0  0.8
[2,]  0.1  0.0    0  0.0
[3,]  0.5  0.0    0  0.0
[4,]  0.4  0.6    0  0.8
```

given that column three in both matrices in lsMat1 are all 0, this seems more correct.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for typo in my example.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question i would do a element-wise  matrix multiplication. Im not familiar with the syntax you posted but IN MATLAB:

mat1 .* mat3

Now all elements that are zero in your binary matrix will stay zero, and all that are one will become the value from your qualitative matrix.

Hope it helps!